"And " vs "Or" when using respectively
I want to reduce my sentence to a shorter sentence. My actual intention is:

In real-type representations, k is 1, in complex-type representations, k is 2, and in quaternion-type representations, k is 4.

I wrote it as follows:

k is 1, 2, and 4 for real-type, complex-type, and quaternion-type irreducible representation, respectively.

However, my supervisor said the correct sentence is:

k is 1, 2, or 4 for real-type, complex-type, or quaternion-type irreducible representation, respectively.

I thought, since in the actual sentence I have "and", in the reduced one I need to use "and". However, because it is describing three distinct cases and each case is exclusive, we need to use "or".
Would someone explain this to me? In grammatical English classes, I have learned to think like the first case.

I'd be tempted to leave out the first coordinator. k is 1, 2, 4 for real-type, complex-type, and quaternion-type irreducible representations, respectively.

I think you can use either, as long as you're consistent. But I also think "or" is more common.

If k=1 for real-types, there's no choice. I'd interpret or to say there's a choice. Anyway, more compact isn't always clearer.

I would use and rather than or. And by the way, you can shorten the sentence further like this: “The value of k is 1, 2, and 4 for real-, complex-, and quaternion-type irreducible representations, respectively.” I prepended The value of because it’s not cool to start sentences with lower-case variables (or with numbers not spelled out). And note that representations is plural.

Perhaps your supervisor thought, as I do but k is not 1 and 2 and 4, rather k is 1 or 2 or 4.  The mental chunking we use to parse the sentence is materially affected by the rewrite from the first version to the second.

Whatever the technically correct answer to the question, as posed, is, the best thing to do is use the very first, long, version, and not attempt to shorten it. Shortening the sentence saves a very small amount of space at the price of imposing extra work on the reader and creating a risk of a misunderstanding.


k is 1, 2, and 4 for real-type, complex-type, and quaternion-type irreducible representation, respectively.

k is 1, 2, or 4 for real, complex, and quaternion type representations respectively.

However I suspect that the concept of a "type representation" is not needed as these could just be "types".

Within mathematics Real, Complex, and Quaternion are respectively 1, 2 and 4 dimensional rings, a ring is type of abstract algebraic structure with many useful mathematical properties.


Lower-casing of designated variables/constants trumps other demands such as being sentence-initial. g, for instance, must not be confused with G.

This statement mostly clearly and concisely reflects your intended meaning:

For real-, complex- and quaternion-type representations, the value of k is 1, 2 and 4, respectively.


my supervisor said that the correct sentence is:

k is 1, 2, or 4 for real-type, complex-type, or quaternion-type irreducible representation, respectively.

because it is describing three distinct cases and each case is exclusive, we need to use "or".

There is no particular basis for assuming that the disjunction in "...or.....or..., respectively" should be exclusive; after all, the conjunction in "...and.....and..., respectively" certainly does not mean that the cases overlap!
Thus, whenever "...and.....and..., respectively" is appropriate, opting for the unorthodox "...or.....or..., respectively" adds no value and just feels distractingly out of left field.

On the other hand, the following are two related  "....respectively" examples (the second one from here), where opting for or instead of and is appropriate (note that neither case contravenes my previous paragraph).

The light might turn red or amber, in which case you should press their respective buttons.
If the light changes from red to blue or from blue to red, you must catch and throw the ball, respectively.

